# The construction of the sentences

Tags: sentence-construction

Having saw the sentence”needless to say”, I thought it was kind of leaving out, and the original form, in my guess, was like “(conjunction + it is) adjective(needless) to intransitive(say)”.
Then I thought up sentences upon the abstract above, yet don’t know if they are correct or natural. I know whether they are depends, so please tell me if there is a context the sentences below fit naturally.

“Important to say”
“Weird to say”
“Strange to think”

Or are they just idioms to memorize?

Comment: "Having saw the sentence" should be "having seen the sentence."  because it is in the present perfect, see https://forum.thefreedictionary.com/postst49890_HAVING-SEEN-.aspx  The phrase "I thought it was kind of leaving out," is also awkward. A more natural form woul be "I thought it left something out."

Answer (score 1):

*Needless to say* is a phrase, not a sentence, but you are right in thinking that it is short for *It is needless (unnecessary) to say that...*. A few phrases like that are well-established in the English language. *Strange to say* is one (not *weird*, because the use of that word in everyday language is modern). There's also *wonderful to relate*, mainly as a translation of the Latin *mirabile dictu (wonderful* here means *remarkable*, not *very good).*

I don't think you can use *important to say* on its own.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase (not a sentence) "Needless to say" is a ***fixed phrase***. See [Are idioms not recommended in a formal situation?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/299986/are-idioms-not-recommended-in-a-formal-situation/299990#299990) for more on fixed phrases.

It is short for

> It is needless to say ...

or

> It would be needless to say ...

or in still fuller form

> It is (or would be) needless for me to say ...

It is a slightly odd phrase because the speaker or writer says that it is needless (not required) to say something, and then goes on to say it anyway. It is often used for emphasis. For example:

> An hour into the date, I called Betty "June" by msitake. Betty and June had been funding for years. Needless to say I didn't get anywhere on **that** date.

The speaker wants to emphasize how obvious it would be that the date was a failure.

Another example:

> Columbus thought that he could get to the spice and silk markets of India and China by sailing east across the Atlantic. Needless to say, North and South America were a significant obstacle to this plan.

The  writer wants to emphasize ho much Columbus did not know about the state of the world.

“Weird to say” is not such a standard fixed phrase, and would sound odd to many fluent speakers. The same is true of "Important to say" That would be better rendered as "It is important for me to mention that..."